# Should SQLite queries be in Async Task Android

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-contentprovider, android-syncadapter

I am going to be implementing an abstractsyncadapter for my application by means of creating an account for the user using the account authentication. This means all of my REST method calls will be put into the sync service to be completed. My question in relation to this is should all of my contentprovider calls be done from a separate thread like an Async task? Or should I create a separate class that extends async task? I just want to know best practice for my applications purposes.

If anyone has any examples of this implementation with a syncadapter that would be awesome, although it seems unlikely, because I have looked EVERYWHERE.

Thanks for any advice you have!

Comment: Calls to a `ContentProvider` should always be made off the main UI thread.

Comment: @Luksprog Do you have any examples of exactly how this is implemented? Because I feel if I do it in a seperate asynctask method it still slows down my UI.